# Не работает анимация в первом столбце

Tags: javascript, html

В первом столбце описание полей, во втором значения. По нажатии одной из трех кнопок именяется значения во втором столбце. Всего их три. Я не могу понять как можно сделать чтобы работала анимация в первом столбце как во втором. Как можно добавить анимацию к первому столбцу, чтобы была такая же как во втором?

```js
function listClickButton(id) {
      for (let i = 0; i < TableBorder.length; i++) { 
        for (let j = 0; j < ButtonText.length; j++) {
          let elem = TableBorder[i].getElementsByClassName("table_element-mobile")[j];  
          $(elem ).fadeIn(200);
          elem.style.display = id == j ? "table-cell" : "none";
          ButtonText[j].style.backgroundColor = id == j ? "#00c6d3" : "#26275f80";
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="button">
      <div class="button-text">1</div>
      <div class="button-text">2</div>
      <div class="button-text">3</div>
    </div>
    <table id="table_content-mobile">
      <tr class="table_border">
        <th class="table_row_description-mobile">Сумма</th>
        <td class="table_element-mobile">6</td>
        <td class="table_element-mobile">7</td>
        <td class="table_element-mobile">8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table_border">
        <th class="table_row_description-mobile">Доход</th>
        <td class="table_element-mobile">80</td>
        <td class="table_element-mobile">150</td>
        <td class="table_element-mobile">1500</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, написать работающий (почти работающий) код.

Comment: Если выполнить код, никакой анимации нет.